# C++ Static Date Class

Tags: c++, oop, static

For this problem, Im tasked with creating a "Date" class that has only one data member that holds an integer of the number of days from a "Base" date. This is the corresponding header class

```
#ifndef _DATE_H_
#define _DATE_H_

#include <QString>

class Date{
public:
        const static int BaseYear = 1900; 
        Date();
        Date(int y, int m, int d);
        void set(int y, int m, int d);
        QString toString(bool brief);
        void setToToday();
        QString getWeekDay();
        bool lessThan(const Date& d);
        bool equals(const Date& d);
        int daysBetween(const Date& d);
        Date addDate(int Days);
        static bool leapYear(int year);
        static QString monthName(int month);
        static int yearDays(int year);
        static int monthDays(int month, int year);
private:
        int m_DaysSinceBaseDate;
        static int ymd2dsbd(int y, int m, int d);
        void getYMD(int& y, int& m, int& d);
};
#endif
```

Im running into trouble when trying to write out the date to a string, the implementation states that function getYMD() is suppose to help with this computation.

Comment: What trouble are you running into? Does `getYMD` do what you need it to do?

Comment: Just as an aside, is there a specific requirement to use `QString`s as opposed to `std::string`s (or `std::wstring`s)? This doesn't seem like something you would necessarily want to inextricably tie to a specific widget library.

Comment: If `QString` can be considered as a hint that you're using Qt, I'd like to mention [QDate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html).

Comment: I don't understand what the function is suppose to be used for @JohnFilleau is the problem, any idea?

Comment: Yes it was required in the assignment instructions @Schol-R-LEA

Comment: Looks like it's supposed to populate which year, month of the year, and day of the month you're in since the start of the epoch. Any uncertainties like that should definitely be handled by asking your teaching staff. They're being paid actual money to clarify stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already implemented the `getYMD` method, you can use the result of it to fill in a `struct tm` which you can then format as a string using `strftime`:

```
// a class method
QString format() const {
   int y, int m, int d;
   Date date = *this;

   // Passed to strftime(3) 
   char buffer[64];

   date.getYMD(y, m, d);
   struct tm t;

   // This saves you from having to zero out
   // each field manually
   memset(&t, 0, sizeof(struct tm));

   t.tm_year = y - 1900; // since 1900
   t.tm_mon = m - 1; // zero based
   t.tm_day = d;

   const char* format = ""; // insert format here
   size_t length = strftime(buffer, 64, format, &time_struct);
   
   std::string s(buffer, length);
   return QString::FromStdString(s);
}
```